# Configure Static IP Address for Point-to-site VPN in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-vpn

How to configure Point-to-Site VPN with a Static IP address as my applications are dependent on a static IP address given out by the VPN Gateway. Is it even possible with Point-to-site? What about options like ExpressRoute and Site-to-Site VPN?

Answer (score 0):

As of now assigning Static IP for P2S is not possible. Please raise your feedback via User Voice: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking

If you are using options like Site to Site or Express Route, Azure will not lease IP address and basically it connects to the Peer Address Prefix. So you can deploy your Application on On-Premises Server and make that Server IP static to address your issue.